# Bootstrap 3 Tooltip over Glyphicon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, glyphicons

Not sure if this even possible, I am trying to invoke a tooltip over a glyphicon inside an input group, my code (which does not work) is;

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="security" id="security"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container: 'body' title="" data-original-title="Security Code"></span></span>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3, and the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: The "latest" version of jQuery is a moving target. Be specific.

Answer (score 77):

You can get a simple tooltip over the glyphicon using the title attribute (which is blank in your example).

```
title="info"
```

Working code

```
 // add this in your js
 // all the glyphicons having the class "my-tooltip" will show a tooltip if "title" attribute is present
 $(".my-tooltip").tooltip();

 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign my-tooltip' title="here goes the tooltip text"></span>
```

Answer (score 22):

Using @MadJack's answer I rewrote your code and tested on JSFiddle.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group" style='margin-top: 100px;'>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="security" id="security">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <a class='my-tool-tip' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip here">
                <!-- The class CANNOT be tooltip... -->
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></i>
            </a>
        </span>
    </input>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("a.my-tool-tip").tooltip();
```

Hope this helps,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9Ku6/3/).

-Andrew

Answer (score 5):

A Bootstrap newbie here...

To use the Tooltip plugin with the glyph-icon, I've found success wrapping the glyph-icon span tag with an anchor tag having no href:

```
<a data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltipLink" data-original-title="Tooltip text goes here">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
</a>
```

Also, be sure to initialize the tooltips for the links with tooltips:

```
$("a.tooltipLink").tooltip();
```

I tested this with Bootstrap 3.03, jQuery 1.10.2 + Firefox 26, Chrome 32.0.1700, and IE 11.0.9600. So far, no hiccups.

Answer (score 5):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign icon_info" title="info"></span>
```

Then add javascript code to initialize tooltip like below:

```
$(".icon_info").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap's Popover makes it a bit nice,
Here is the 
[documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/), and sample code snippet

```js
$(function () {
  $('.fa').popover({trigger: "hover"});
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Information Popover snippet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Information Popover snippet</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>  
  <span><i data-content="Simple Clean way to show more detailed information about anything" class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span>
</body>
</html>
```