# HTML5/Bootstrap - How do i add tooltip for bootstrap glyphicon icons?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How do i add the tooltip for the below HTML5 statement?

```
<tr><td><a ng-href="#">Call us</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" > </span>

</td>
```

Comment: Just add a `title="tooltip here"`.

Comment: You can check out [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688974/bootstrap-3-tooltip-over-glyphicon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr><td><a ng-href="#">Call us</a>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Call Us"></span>

</td>
```