# Bootstrap Glyphicon Popover

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I was wondering why the following glyphicon doesn't trigger a hover popup..
Could you please advise?

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10 ">
       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign form-control-feedback" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover"  data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Title" data-content="Content"></span>
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class, 
    `form-control-feedback`, from the `<span>` element

https://jsfiddle.net/0uye7njx/

Here's another post if you want the actual "style" of the tooltip

- [Bootstrap 3 Tooltip over Glyphicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688974/bootstrap-3-tooltip-over-glyphicon)
- http://jsfiddle.net/t9Ku6/3/

Comment: if I remove the form-control-feedback the icon goes outside of the control